# Adding dropdown menus with d3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, dropdown

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu using d3 and the [Bootstrap select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) plugin. Here is a working piece of code:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-3" id="test">
  <div class="form-group">
   <select class="selectpicker form-control" id = "opts" >
     <option value="ds1">data1</option>
     <option value="ds2">data2</option> 
     <option value="ds3">data3</option>
   </select> 
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and in this case, I get a dropdown menu, as wanted. I now want to do it programatically with d3 using the following:

```
selectGroup = d3.select("body")
                       .append("div").attr("class","row")
                       .append("div").attr("class","col-xs-3")
                       .append("div").attr("class", "form-group")
                       .append("select").attr("class", "selectpicker form-control");
    selectGroup.append("option").attr("value","key1").text("data1");
    selectGroup.append("option").attr("value","key2").text("data2");
```

When doing so, I see nothing on the screen. In Chrome Elements, I can see this has been added to the DOM, but the dimensions are ...x0, as if it has no height.

Any idea why this is, and how to overcome this? Thanks a lot for all help!

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/barmue5n/?

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! There still appears to be something wrong, as the layout is not as in the documentation of Bootstrap select. Also, when trying to adjust the width using "data-width=...", nothing seems to change... Any ideas? Thanks!